# How can I set the function to render after another function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous

I connected my react app to firebase and I think the problem is that the page loads before the data from my database is acquired, what can I do to delay the function until after it finishes acquiring the data?

```
function getPosts(){
    db.collection("Posts").get().then(snapshot =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(docs =>{
             createPost(
                 docs.data().postName,
                 docs.data().createdAt,
                 docs.data().postContent,
             )
        })
    })
}

getPosts();

function Blog(){
    return (
    <div>
              <Navbar/>
<div className="container">
<div className="row" id="posts-collection">

</div>
</div>
</div>
    )
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Components should be designed to handle all cases: either start off with an empty array of posts so a `map` has no work to do, or handle the "no posts" condition with a different component/render, or... There are many solutions. Not that as it stands there's no rendering of posts in there at all: please try to post code directly related to the question, and take the time to format it nicely so it's easier to think about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MehmetDemiray already shows you can load data as an effect within a function component, but that answer assumes you only wish to track loading status.

If you want to use the data loaded to display the post data then you will also need to store the returned data.

```
const Blog: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    // state to store data returned by async call. (originally set to null).
    const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState(null);

    // use an effect to load async data.
    // the effect only runs on component load and every time the data in
    // the dependency array changes "[setPosts]" (reference comparison).
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Create funtion to run async logic to load posts.
        const getPosts = () => {
            // load posts
            db.collection("Posts").get().then(snapshot => {
                // map loaded posts to an array of easy to manage objects.
                const loadedPosts = snapshot.docs.map(docs => {
                    return {
                        name: docs.data().postName,
                        createdAt: docs.data().createdAt,
                        content: docs.data().postContent,
                    }
                });

                // store loaded posts in state.
                setPosts(loadedPosts ?? []);
            });
        };

        // run async function created above.
        getPosts();
    }, [setPosts])

    // posts will remain null until the async function has loaded data.
    // you can manually track loading in a separate state if required.
    if (posts === null) {
        // Show loading view while loading.
        return (
            <div>
                Loading Posts...
            </div>
        );
    }

    // map out posts view after posts have been loaded.
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map(post => (
                <div>
                    <div>{post.postName}</div>
                    <div>{post.createdAt}</div>
                    <div>{post.content}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loading control before rendering jsx. Looks like this;

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function Blog(){
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    function getPosts(){
      db.collection("Posts").get().then(snapshot =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(docs =>{
          createPost(
            docs.data().postName,
            docs.data().createdAt,
            docs.data().postContent,
          )
        })
      setLoading(false);
      })
    }
    getPosts();
  }, [])

  return (
  loading ? 
  <div>
  < Navbar/>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row" id="posts-collection">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div> : null
  )
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Thanks it did work the first time I tried it, but then I refreshed the page and suddenly nothing was starting to load, I don't know what caused the problem.
Edit: it loads the navbar then the navbar quickly disappears I do not know why : (